# Object Oriented Programming with said methods. Java

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

Rational numbers contain an integer numerator and denominator. Write the code to implement a class named Rational which stores two private ints (numer and denom) with the following methods:

**public Rational(int,int)**
*constructor that sets the numer and denom*

**public Rational(Rational)**

*//copy constructor for a Rational object*

**public void setNumer(int)** 
*//sets the numerator to the paramter value*

**public int getNumer()**
*//returns the stored numerator*

**public void setDenom(int)** 
*//sets the denominator to the paramter value*

**public int getDenom()**     *//returns the stored denominator*

*//return a new Rational object that contains the reciprocal of the object that invokes the method.*

**public Rational reciprocal()**

*//returns a new Rational object that contains the product of the two paramteres.*

**public static Rational multiply(Rational a, Rational b)**

---

I am stuck at the 7th method for this class. I don't understand how to flip the numbers so that they are reciprocals. Any help will be greatly Appreciated. This is my code so far:

```
class Rational {
    private int numer;
    private int denom;

    public Rational(int numer, int denom){
        this.numer = numer;
        this.denom = denom;
    }

    public Rational(Rational rational){
        rational = new Rational(numer, denom);
    }

    public void setNumber(int fum){
        numer = fum;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return 5;
    }

    public void setDenom(int Dum){
        denom = Dum;
    }

    public int getDenom(){
        return 10;
    }

    public Rational reciprocal(){
        ;
    }
}



public class Results {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

}
```

Comment: And for the last one I was trying this: public static Rational multiply(Rational a, Rational b) {  return new Rational(a*b). And can't pass that. I'm confused.

Comment: What's a copy constructor? This is Java!

Comment: I take it a copy constructor, is not a Java terminology. I've been trying to do the last one, but I get that my method is undefined Rational. Why is this exactly? And what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You should use separate files for each Java class. Currently your class is package private (without `public` or `protected` in front of it). Maybe that has something to do with it? You would not need a copy constructor if you make the class *immutable*; you could just copy the reference. But maybe that's a next lession.

Comment: Nitpicking: The description for `reciprocal()` is wrong. Instead of "*… of the object that invokes the method.*" it should read something like "*… of the object the method is called on.*".

Answer (score 3):

[Math is Fun: Reciprocal of a Fraction](https://www.mathsisfun.com/reciprocal-fraction.html) says (in part) *to get the reciprocal of a fraction, just turn it upside down.*

```
public Rational reciprocal(){
    return new Rational(this.denom, this.number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Rational reciprocal(){
  return new Rational(denom, numer);
}
```

It get the reciprocal which is just the numerator and denominator flipped.  `return new Rational(denom, numer);` does this by creating a new rational instance with the denominator from the current one as the numerator and as the numerator as the current instance as the denominator.

Really a reciprocal is one divided by the original number as said [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/reciprocal.html), but flipping the numerator and denominator does the same thing as dividing by its self.

Comment: But I don't have to divide, in the method? I was trying something like this: return new Rational(denom/numer);

Comment: So when I call it in the main, would it automatically look like this: (10/5)?

Comment: @userb I fixed my definition.  Re-read it.  Try the code I posted.  `return new Rational(denom, numer);` will return the reciprocal.  A recipicol is 1 / x. Example: reciprocal of 8 equals 1/8.  Reciprocal of 3/8 equals 1 / (3/8) simplified to 8/3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a new Rational with the numbers fliped.

```
public Rational reciprocal(){
    return new Rational(this.denom,this.numer);
}
```